# How to make authorization system with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app users can belongs to many companies, companies may have many users, one user can operate in two or more companies, in company can have different roles, for example in company 1 user maybe administrator and in company 2 maybe secretary. I create models Company User and Role

Company.rb

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_companies
  has_many :users, through: :users_companies
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies, through: :users_companies
  has_many :users_companies
  has_many :users_roles, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :roles, through: :users_roles
end
```

Role.rb

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_roles
  has_many :users, through: :users_roles
end
```

then i create models UsersCompany UsersRole

users_role.rb

```
class UsersRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
  #belongs_to :company
end
```

Users_role.rb

```
class UsersRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
  #belongs_to :company
end
```

And add to users_roles db column company_id to determine the company for the user but when i update user model to add or remove role, company_id column will be null. I think its a bad idea and there is a correct solution to this problem.

This in my views

```
<%= form_for([@company, @user]) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :last_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>

    <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, type: "text" %>

    <%= f.label :middle_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :middle_name, type: "text" %>

    <%= hidden_field_tag "user[role_ids][]", nil %>
    <% Role.all.each do |role| %>
      <%= check_box_tag "user[role_ids][]", role.id, @user.role_ids.include?(role.id), id: dom_id(role) %>
      <%= label_tag dom_id(role), role.second_name %><br>
      <% end %>
    <%= f.submit, class: "login loginmodal-submit", type: "submit"  %>
<% end %>
```

and users controller update action

```
def update
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    redirect_to :back if @user.update 
end
```

how to build a system of authorization if the user at the same time can work in two different companies with different roles?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why when you update role, the company_id become null, but in your conceptual model the user can have many roles at the same company, which i think is wrong. Further, it seems like the the company_user (which is the basic relation between the company and the user) doesn't have to do anything with user_role, and that makes the update and the track of which user has which role in which company hard.

I would like to suggest those class models in order to get the relationship between user, role and company.

```
class User
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :companies, through: :user_roles
end

class Company
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :users, through: :user_roles
end

class UserRole
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :role
end

class Role
  has_many :user_roles
end
```

I think you know what to do with the migrations.